# How to Remove Specific object from arrayList using Javascript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I have two objects like this.

```
var find = [{
    licenseId: 'A123',
    batchId: '123',
    name: 'xxx'
},
    {
        licenseId: 'B123',
        batchId: '124',
        name: 'yyy'
    }];


var result = [
    {
        licenseId: 'A123',
        batchId: '123',
        name: 'xxx',
        tag: 'college',
        sem: 'fourth'
    },

    {
        licenseId: 'B123',
        batchId: '124',
        name: 'yyy',
        tag: 'college',
        sem: 'third'
    },
    {
        licenseId: '1111',
        batchId: 'C123',
        name: 'yyy',
        tag: 'college',
        sem: 'second'
    },


    {
        licenseId: '3456',
        batchId: 'B123',
        name: 'yyy',
        tag: 'college',
        sem: 'second'
    }];
```

I want to remove the objects of **Result** which has matched with all three properties of **find** object. I want the result should be like this:

```
[{
        licenseId: '1111',
        batchId: 'C123',
        name: 'yyy',
        tag: 'college',
        sem: 'second'
    },


    {
        licenseId: '3456',
        batchId: 'B123',
        name: 'yyy',
        tag: 'college',
        sem: 'second'
    }];
```

Can you assist?

Comment: Please post your efforts

Comment: Are you sure thats how you want the end result to look like? I mean you take a licenseId and put it as a batchId. And in the end result you have a licenseId of 3456 but that does not even exist in the starting array.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work.

```
for(var j=0;j < find.length;j++){
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if ((result[i].licenseId == find[j].licenseId)  && 
        (result[i].name == find[j].name) && 
        (result[j].batchId == find[j].batchId)) {
      result.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find if the result array has the matched element. Here `licenseId` is used to find if result array contain the same element.

If it is found there use `index` argument to find it's index. Then use `splice` to delete the specific element.

also you can use array `forEach` to loop through the `find` array

```
var find = [// json objects];

var result = [// json objects];
find.forEach(function(item){

var _findInResult = result.find(function(itemInResult,index){
   if(itemInResult.licenseId == item.licenseId){
   result.splice(index,1);
   }
   return itemInResult.licenseId == item.licenseId
})

})
console.log(result)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/63s6t778/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [remove](https://lodash.com/docs#remove) and [some](https://lodash.com/docs#some)

```
_.remove(result, function(obj) {
    return _.some(find, {
        licenseId: obj.licenseId,
        batchId: obj.batchId,
        name: obj.name,
    });
});
```

```js
var find = [{
  licenseId: 'A123',
  batchId: '123',
  name: 'xxx'
},
{
  licenseId: 'B123',
  batchId: '124',
  name: 'yyy'
}];

var result = [
{
  licenseId: 'A123',
  batchId: '123',
  name: 'xxx',
  tag: 'college',
  sem: 'fourth'
},
{
  licenseId: 'B123',
  batchId: '124',
  name: 'yyy',
  tag: 'college',
  sem: 'third'
},
{
  licenseId: '1111',
  batchId: 'C123',
  name: 'yyy',
  tag: 'college',
  sem: 'second'
},
{
  licenseId: '3456',
  batchId: 'B123',
  name: 'yyy',
  tag: 'college',
  sem: 'second'
}];

_.remove(result, function(obj) {
  return _.some(find, {
    licenseId: obj.licenseId,
    batchId: obj.batchId,
    name: obj.name,
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```